# Adobe Site Catalyst capturing success with events vs PageViews

Tags: adobe-analytics

In our website which uses adobe analytics, we have a functionality where user submits a service request. When he submits the request, the `pageName` that we sent is "`myapp:service-request-submitted"`. We are also capturing this in an event say `event6`.
Each time the user submits the service request as per my understanding, the "`Occurrence`" or "`PageViews`" should increase by "`1`" right? The same should happen with event count also. Is this assumption correct?

But unfortunately, when I checked the report suite, there is a big difference in these numbers. `PageViews` is much higher than (30% more) `event6` count.

Is there any logical reason for this behavior? Or my understanding of events and pageView count calculation is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct... if every time that pageName gets sent on a beacon, you are also setting event6, then I would expect the numbers to match.
Some things that may be happening here:
Does event6 have any sort of serialization turned on? In the Adobe Analytics Admin Console, you can specify if an event should "always be captured" (the default option), count "once per visit", or count "once per unique ID" (so you could have it tied to a confirmation number). I'd check on that.
Is there a chance that pageName is getting set on beacons without that event6 set? Are there other beacons firing on that page (beyond just the pageload)?